# OpenGL: Convert on screen coordinate to OpenGL coordinates

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, touch-event

I draw changing bar in OpenGL ES it has coords (x,y,z).
I would like to add some changes (example: colors in bar) on Action_Down. There is `getX()`, but this method returns the x coordinate in pixels, but not corresponding coords in OpenGL. Is there some class to convert OpenGL coords to pixels? Or is there any formula for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluProject.xml

It takes coordinates and maps them to window coordinates, with (0, 0) at the top left.

Comment: thx, but I cannot get any data from any matrix when I use  gl11.glGetFloatv(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, params,0);  in params are only 0 and result gluProject is NaN.

Comment: Updated the link, qwerty9967. Thanks for the heads up.